# Kotlin - NestedScrollView gets stuck when an editText is focused

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, focus, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `NestedScrollView` with multiple `editTexts`. When I have an `editText` focused, it just doesn't let make scroll around the activity, because the `editText` just gets stuck on the limit of the frame (top or bottom, depending on the direction I'd make scroll). I get a solution for it, but it gets me on a new problem: sometimes `editTexts` gets unfocused because android automatically scrolls to them whenever I touched. So I have to click again to recover the focus. Here's the code for this semi-solution:

```
private fun scrollChangeListener() {
     editText16.clearFocus()
}
```

I don't think it matters, but here is the code of `nesteScrollView` and one of the `editTexts`:

NestedScrollView:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

EditText:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText16"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:inputType="numberDecimal|textNoSuggestions"
      android:maxLength="4"
      android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    />
```